# undefined method `image' for #<Location 0x..>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paperclip

I am using the Paperclip gem. A user can submit a location with an image. I do not want the user to duplicate an already submitted location, but they can add an image to it.

I have been trying to figure it out. I will leave the important code below:

#### location.rb

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :submissions
  has_many :users, through: :submissions
  # Allows submission objects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :submissions
```

#### submission.rb

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "150x150#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

#### locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  # Before actions get routed and ran, find_location will occur
  before_action :find_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # For the Locations/index.html.erb
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
  end

  # Binds submission object to the form in new.html.erb
  def new
    @locations = Location.new
    @locations.submissions.build
  end

  # For creating a new location in the new.html.erb form
  def create
    @locations = Location.new(user_params)
    # Everything went well. User will be sent to @locations show page
    if  @locations.save
      # Redirects to user submitted locations
      redirect_to @locations
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  # Finds new location user submitted by its unique id
  def show
  end

  # Allowing user to update their submitted location
  def edit
  end

  # Updates users edited submission
  def update
    if @locations.update(user_params)
      # Redirects to user submitted locations
      redirect_to @locations
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  # Deletes users submission
  def destroy
    @locations.destroy
    # Redirects to user submitted locations
    redirect_to @locations
  end

  private

  # Used for finding user submitted location (Prevents DRY)
  def find_location
    @locations = Location.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Strong parameters for security - Defines what can be update/created in location model
  def user_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:city, :state, :submissions_attributes => [:image])
  end
end
```

#### _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @locations, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
.
.
.
<!--  User enters image-->
  <%= f.fields_for :submissions do |s| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3>Upload Image:</h3>
    <%= s.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### show.html.erb

```
<h3>Image: <%= image_tag @locations.image.url(:medium) %></h3>
```

I get an error:

```
"undefined method `image' for.."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do form tags for collections of records, which I don't think will work. Instead, I think you need a structure something like:

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= form_for location, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  .
  .
  .
  <!--  User enters image-->
  <%= f.fields_for location.submissions.new do |s| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3>Upload Image:</h3>
      <%= s.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

both the `form_for` and `fields_for` need to point to a singular resource.

Side note: [Paperclip has been deprecated](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#deprecated), and it is recommended that you instead use the Rails internal ActiveStorage.

Comment: So I took your advise and converted to ActiveStorage. I think my main problem is that I have a Many-To-Many relationship which is throwing me off. I think I am able to add an image but I am having trouble displaying it. In my show.html.erb for locations I have "<%= image_tag(@locations.image) %>" and I am still getting the same error as above. Do you have any clue on what I should do here?

Comment: So the thing to keep in mind here is that you're dealing with an array of locations that each have an array of submissions with images. So you need to loop over the locations, then loop over each location's submissions, then render an image tag for each of those. Something like `<% @locations.each do |location| %><% location.submissions.each do |submission| %><%= image_tag(submission.image) %><% end %><% end %>`.